# Gradle - Including other project causes error

Tags: java, gradle

I have cloned [this github repo](https://github.com/sacOO7/socketcluster-client-java), created a new branch and wanted to include that local project in another gradle project.

So, my folder structure is

```
+- socketcluster-client-java (github project)
+---- build.gradle
+---- settings.gradle

+- Project
+----- build.gradle
+----- settings.gradle
```

So, socketcluster-client-java is a dependency in Project. This is the settings.gradle file in Project

```
rootProject.name = 'Project'

include ':socketcluster-client-java'
project(':socketcluster-client-java').projectDir = new File('/path/to/socketcluster-client-java')
```

And I this is what I included in build.gradle of Project

```
dependencies {
   compile project(':socketcluster-client-java')
}
```

However, when I refresh the dependencies (Gradle -> refresh gradle project), I get

```
    org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not fetch model of type 'EclipseProject' using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.9-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultModelBuilder.get(DefaultModelBuilder.java:49)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingclient.internal.DefaultToolingClient.executeAndWait(DefaultToolingClient.java:95)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingclient.internal.DefaultModelRequest.executeAndWait(DefaultModelRequest.java:79)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository$13.get(DefaultModelRepository.java:331)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.executeAndWait(DefaultModelRepository.java:420)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.access$200(DefaultModelRepository.java:67)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository$14.call(DefaultModelRepository.java:353)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4724)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4721)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.getFromCache(DefaultModelRepository.java:369)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.executeRequest(DefaultModelRepository.java:350)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.executeRequest(DefaultModelRepository.java:326)
    at com.gradleware.tooling.toolingmodel.repository.internal.DefaultModelRepository.fetchEclipseGradleBuild(DefaultModelRepository.java:226)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.SynchronizeGradleProjectJob.forceReloadEclipseGradleBuild(SynchronizeGradleProjectJob.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.SynchronizeGradleProjectJob.runToolingApiJobInWorkspace(SynchronizeGradleProjectJob.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiWorkspaceJob$1.run(ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.runInWorkspace(ToolingApiWorkspaceJob.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testRuntime'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:367)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:342)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access
```

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT**

I can include the socketcluster-client-java via `compile group: 'io.github.sac', name: 'SocketclusterClientJava', version: '1.7.2'` but I need to work with my own branch.

**EDIT2**

I just tested this situation with two mock projects and I can include one in the other as dependency without any problems. I am quite confused now

**EDIT3**

The exception below is caused by `Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':testRuntime'.`

**EDIT4**

Here are the logs from `gradle build --refresh-dependencies --info --debug`

```
    07:33:55.020 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Calculate task graph'
07:33:55.025 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
07:33:55.026 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
07:33:55.026 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
07:33:55.026 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
07:33:55.026 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileJava'.
07:33:55.026 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
07:33:55.026 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve project :socketcluster-client-java.
07:33:55.027 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
07:33:55.028 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :
07:33:55.028 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       > Unable to find a matching configuration of project :socketcluster-client-java: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

**EDIT5**

I have created a github [project](https://github.com/MaxHoefl/SocketclusterclientExample) which plays the role of `Project` in the problem description. I get the exact same error as described above when I try to include the socketcluster-client-java github project in this `Project` the way I described above.

Comment: I've just set it up as you described it and it all works fine. Maybe add sample project which shows the error.

Comment: Please see EDIT5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are steps I've just taken and it all works fine:

- `cd /tmp`
- `git clone https://github.com/MaxHoefl/SocketclusterclientExample.git`
- `git clone git clone https://github.com/sacOO7/socketcluster-client-java.git`
- `cd SocketclusterclientExample/Project`
- edit `settings.gradle` substitute `project(':socketcluster-client-java').projectDir = new File('/Users/mh/workspaceJava/socketcluster-client-java')` with `project(':socketcluster-client-java').projectDir = new File('/tmp/socketcluster-client-java')`
- `gradle clean build` - BUILD SUCCESSFUL.